# IF Formula in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to do a nested if statement within **powerbi**, I need to have multiple if statements in one column with some returning - value depending on the if statement.

I have tried to below however theyre all coming back as false.

```
Calculated value = if('TableName'[ColumnName1] = "exp1" && 'TableName'[columnName2] = "exp2", 'TableName'[value]|| if('TableName'[ColumnName1] = "exp1" && 'TableName'[ColumnName2] = "exp3", - 'TableName'[value],""))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first if you don't have any output to the false result. I Add an extra empty value in your calculated value as below only to exemplify what you need to add:

```
Calculated value = if('TableName'[ColumnName1] = "exp1" && 'TableName'[columnName2] = "exp2", 'TableName'[value]|| if('TableName'[ColumnName1] = "exp1" && 'TableName'[ColumnName2] = "exp3", - 'TableName'[value],""),"")
```

Check the example and tell something about this, please